# Installing Python on Windows Multipoint Server 2010

Tags: installation, python, windows-multipoint-server

I am trying to install python latest version in Multipoint Server 2010 but the installation failed due to lack of Service Pack 1.  I searched for SP1 in Microsoft Website but could not find any. My questions are:

- Does Microsoft provide Service Pack for Multipoint Server 2010?
- Does Python not support Multipoint Server 2010?
- Is there any way we could probably install Python in Multipoint Server 2010?

We used Multipoint Server for our institution. As such we really need to install Python for teaching and learning purposes. Lately I learned that Multipoint Server was built on top of Windows Server 2008 R2. Will it be applicable to install Windows 7 SP1 because Windows Server 2008 R2 is a server variant of Windows 7.

Comment: Nope, you need Multipoint Server 2011. Or later. You probably should just go ahead and upgrade to Server 2019; you should already have migration plans waiting to go, since 2010 is getting close to end of support.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, Does that mean it is not compatible to install Windows sp1 at all?

Comment: There wasn't an "SP1". That was Multipoint Server 2011.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Your comments sound more like an answer than comments on the question. Have you considered posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Microsoft Multipoint Server 2010 was built on top of Windows Server 2008 R2 which also used the same SP1 used by Windows 7, the installation was successful.
[image]